# Same form to open with different content

Tags: vb.net, winforms

So I'm building a simple windows tool to display different embeded videos and some tips as technical support for a specific department on my company. The thing is that I have in line more than 50 videos I want to display and I do not want to create a form for each one of them. The idea is to have 2 forms, one where I have the list of videos and by clicking on the desired tutorial it opens a new form where the video would run. So I'm basically looking for a way of getting one form that displays different contents depending on the selected video. Is it possible? this is how i'm doing it now for 1 video:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim MyHTMLCode As String = "<object width=" & C() & "420" & C() & " height=" & C() & "315" & C() & " src=" & C() & "//www.youtube.com/embed/W7W8VjKIBUY" & C() & " frameborder=" & C() & "0" & C() & " allowfullscreen></object>"
    Me.WebBrowser1.DocumentText = MyHTMLCode
    Me.WebBrowser1.Update()

End Sub
Private Function C() As Object
    Return Convert.ToChar(34)

End Function
```

Any help welcome.

Regards

Comment: That's not what the "embedded" tag is for.

Comment: Oh...sorry Jonathon Reinhart :S i'll remove the embedded tag

Comment: Company policies they want it in a tool that can be certified within certain standards.

Comment: create a property on the display form an push data to it from the other

Comment: So on the display form i will have clickable elements that on click will display form 2 with different data..sounds a good idea...thanks Plutonix!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've sorted out my problem in a simple way by adding an action to each button/list item to navigate on webbrowser plugin. Works wonders! Thank you all for your time. See my code below:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim form As New Form2
    form.Show()
    form.WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.youtube.com/embed/VeWYQPxzNZo")
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim form As New Form2
    form.Show()
    form.WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.youtube.com/embed/ghqVadag1-8")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a Constructor to your Form to receive the URL:

```
    Dim f1 As New Form1("www.youtube.com/embed/W7W8VjKIBUY")
    f1.Show()
```

In Form1:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private _URL As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal URL As String)
        Me.InitializeComponent()
        Me._URL = URL
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim MyHTMLCode As String = "<object width=" & C() & "420" & C() & " height=" & C() & "315" & C() & " src=" & C() & "//" & Me._URL & C() & " frameborder=" & C() & "0" & C() & " allowfullscreen></object>"
        Me.WebBrowser1.DocumentText = MyHTMLCode
        Me.WebBrowser1.Update()
    End Sub

    Private Function C() As Object
        Return Convert.ToChar(34)
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: With this approach for next video, he will need to create new instance of Display form. There must be method with parameter `url`, which update `url` and call `WebBeowser.Update` method

Comment: True.  It was unclear to me if he really only wanted one instance of the second form, or if he was just asking how to get around building 50 different forms, each with a hard-coded URL.